# formset_factory validation in django

Tags: django, django-forms

How to set validations in the first fields of NicheSkills form when no input is given and i click save button.I want the error to be shown as "This field is required" when no input is given in first row. Kindly Help me.

Models.py:

```
class NicheSkills(Audit):
    user                    = models.ForeignKey(User, null = True, blank = True)      
    title                   = models.CharField(max_length = 15)    
    special_skill           = models.CharField(max_length = 15)
```

Forms.py:

```
class NicheSkillsForm(forms.Form):
    title                   = fields.CharField(max_length=150)
    special_skill           = fields.CharField(max_length=150)

NicheFormset = formsets.formset_factory(NicheSkillsForm, extra = 1)
```

Template:

```
<table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3" border="0" style="margin-left:65px;">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr><td>{{ form5.current_role }}</td></tr>
                            <tr><td><span class = "forget-errors">{{ form5.current_role.errors }}</span></td></tr>
                            <tr><td align="center"><input type="button"   id="form5" name="save" value="Save" onclick = "save_form(this.id)" /></td></tr>
                        </tbody>
</table>
```

Views.Py

```
NicheFormset = formsets.formset_factory(NicheSkillsForm, extra = 0)
if request.method == "POST":
    formset6 = NicheFormset(request.POST, prefix='fs6')
    if formset6.is_valid():
        for values in formset6.cleaned_data:
            niche_details = NicheSkills(
                                    title          = values['title'],
                                    special_skill     = values['special_skill'])

            niche_details.save()  
else:
    NicheFormset = formsets.formset_factory(NicheSkillsForm, extra = 1)
    formset6 = NicheFormset(prefix='fs6')        
return render_to_response('test.html', locals(), RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: "No input is given" means "there is a field with no input" or "all fields have no input" ?

Comment: All fields have no input

Answer (score 1):

Use [Django Forms validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation), define `clean()` method for your form class and validate fields within.

If you want to display an error for a whole form - just raise a `ValidationError` with proper error description.

If you want to display a field-related error (e.g. connected to the first blank field), you have to modify `self._errors[field]`.

It's all described in a linked part of a documentation. The example of using `self._errors` is at the end, in the last code snippet.

Comment: But for formset is it posssible to use validations as in form?

Comment: I'm pretty sure, that every form in formset is normally validated during a construction.

Comment: @WojciechŻółtak It looks no, None of the form is validating in django when it's build using formset_factory.